# I2C Symbolic Link

Tags: c, linux-kernel, i2c, device-tree

In linux you are able to use the ln command to link files/folders together to create symbolic files/folders. Is there a way to do the same thing but with i2c master addresses.

Ex: i2c-this -> i2c-06

So that when my code calls on "i2c-this", the address "i2c-06" is the one actually being called.

Comment: is `i2c-this` a file/device file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.  See https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/i2c/dev-interface.

```
  int file;
  int adapter_nr = 2; /* probably dynamically determined */
  char filename[20];

  snprintf(filename, 19, "/dev/i2c-%d", adapter_nr);
  file = open(filename, O_RDWR);
  if (file < 0) {
    /* ERROR HANDLING; you can check errno to see what went wrong */
    exit(1);
  }
```

To instantiate a user space driver, follow method 4 from Yes.  https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/i2c/instantiating-devices . Specifically, your script will have to create the device in the /dev/ tree after adding the I2C device to the device tree since /dev is handled dynamically.

Comment: Is this possible within the device tree?

Comment: Yes, that's literally in the example provided.  I put it into my solution. Notice the path.

Comment: sorry I should've clarified. Is this possible within a .dtsi file?